# How to sort custom post type posts in default order by multiple fields?

Tags: custom-post-types, pre-get-posts

I'm with a non-profit that paid for development of a custom post type plugin that will help us track endangered plants that we're keeping in cultivation, rescued from development. We're mostly happy with it, but need a bit of help. Our plugin is called nasc_report and we have multiple "authors" who are generating reports. The plants are cared for over time, so each year we ask for a census to be taken. So I'd like the default sort order to be ruled first by author (each author's posts will be grouped) and then by nasc_population_code (A to Z), and then by date (most recent on top). This will produce little groups of our cultivated plant material by population code but separate them by author.

(As an aside, our growers are assigned a separate role that only allows them to see their own entries - all entries are private - but admins unfortunately see all and can't hide all but their own; admins are also usually growers. Any ideas on that would be welcomed as well. If we could allow admins the options: "All | Private | Mine" and make "Mine" the default screen, then I'd only need to default sort by nasc_population_code and then by date.)

I've searched around but haven't found a direct answer to my question or if I have I haven't been able to understand it very well. Would I use pre_get_posts? I'm just a little lost in the code, here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you please try to reduce your question a little? It's hard to understand this way, as there's a lot of "noise" in it. You can also try to use the editor format buttons like list, etc. to give it more structure. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry - I thought it was fairly concise. I'm way outside my comfort zone so in discussing these topics I feel I needed to add more description to get my point across since I don't know the proper code or terms. I'm a botanist, not a programmer.

Comment: It's 3 years later but it must be pointed out that a question which contains an "aside" in parenthesis that occupies one COMPLETE paragraph does not even come close to "fairly concise".

Answer (score 3):

Since I just wrote a `pre_get_posts` answer for someone else, I will modify it slightly and see if it works for you too.

When using `pre_get_posts` the $query variable is passed "by reference" which means we can directly manipulate the `$query` object with the shortcut functions such as `set_query_var`. Remove the query code from your taxonomy template, and try the following in your functions.php:

```
function wpa_66507( $query ) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive('nasc_report ') && is_main_query() ) { //where 'nasc_report' is assumed to be your post type name
        set_query_var( 'orderby', 'author meta_value date' );
        set_query_var( 'meta_key', 'nasc_population_code' ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_66507' );
```

Hope this helps.  I'm a little unclear on sort orders (particularly whether they can be *mixed*), and I think you might need to set the `posts_per_page` parameter to `-1` if you'd like to show *all* your posts on a single page without pagination.

**EDIT #1:**

I took another look at this and actually tested on some sample posts.  It sorts by:

1. Post author's display name (instead of author ID) - ascending
2. Post meta key nasc_population_code - ascending
3. Post date - descending

To do this we can no longer use the *relatively* simple `pre_get_posts` and have to do more custom SQL.  I apologize in advance that I won't be able to explain it amazingly well because my own understanding is sort of limited.  WordPress has a bunch of other filters that let you adjust the actual SQL query WordPress intends to perform on the database to retrieve your posts.  The ones I'm using here are:

1. [posts_join](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join) -  in general this links other tables to the wp_posts table
2. [posts_orderby](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby) - this controls the ordering
3. [post_limits](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_limits) - this controls how many posts to retrieve

The Codex entries are admittedly a little *thin* and I find them somewhat confusing.

**edit:** This solution also presumes that you have a meta key ( custom field, practically same difference ) called `nasc_population_code`.

So putting it all together, give this a try:

```
add_filter('posts_join', 'wpa_66507_join');

function wpa_66507_join( $join ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('nasc_report') && is_main_query() )  {

        global $wpdb;

        // join the users table so we can sort by author name
        $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->users AS author ON ( {$wpdb->posts}.post_author = author.id )";

        // join the postmeta table so we can sort by meta key
        $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS nasc_population_code ON ( {$wpdb->posts}.ID = nasc_population_code.post_id AND nasc_population_code.meta_key = 'nasc_population_code' )";
    }
    return $join;
}

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'wpa_66507_orderby');

function wpa_66507_orderby($orderby_statement) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('nasc_report') && is_main_query() )  {
        global $wpdb;
        $orderby_statement = "author.display_name ASC, nasc_population_code.meta_value ASC";
    }
    return $orderby_statement;
}

add_filter('post_limits', 'wpa_66507_limits');

function wpa_66507_limits($limits) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('nasc_report') && is_main_query() )  {
        $limits = "";
    }
    return $limits;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I have a feeling I'll need to stare at this code for a while longer this weekend to understand it. (For instance, I don't think I have a taxonomy template. These posts aren't hierarchical, although come to think of it perhaps they should be: maybe all previous posts should be nested under the most recent population code entry for that author so only the most recent one shows but the others can be expanded...)

Comment: Anyway, I threw the code in (nasc_report and nasc_population_code are correct) but it still default sorts by the generated title, "Report 735."

I'll keep working on it. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. I wasn't sure that `pre_get_posts` would work for such a complex query, or if you'd need something more advanced: like a custom query.  And the reference to taxonomy template is left over from the other answer I was working on re: `pre_get_posts`.  If you don't have one, you must be falling back to archives.php? or perhaps index.php?

Comment: No worries. Perhaps I could take a different approach. If I fixed the problem so that admins by default saw only their private posts (but could see and administrate "All" if they clicked All at the top if they chose) then I could use the 'nasc_population_code' as a custom taxonomy... maybe? Perhaps it's obvious, but I seem to be in over my head and don't have the time to learn the language. Might have to go back to the original plugin developer and ask for modifications :-/ Thanks for your time and the explanations!

Comment: Wow! Thanks for taking another stab at this. I threw the updated version into functions.php but it still default sorts by date. To clarify, the column `nasc_population_code` isn't hard-coded in the plugin anywhere - would that cause a problem? The plugin developer allowed us to choose the fields we want to incorporate, such as pot size or plant height, as we may want to change them in the future easily. The columns in the custom post type are added to an array in a separate options page and given the id "nasc_field_id" hence `nasc_population_code`, but it should still be able to sort by it...

Comment: You should at the very least be sorted by author "name" now.  If not, then I suspect you have interference coming from somewhere else.  Also, `nasc_population_code` must be postmeta/custom field for this to work as written.  If nothing is happening then you must not have any postmeta/custom field called `nasc_population_code`.  I don't understand your reference to columns and separate options pages, so I don't know how your plugin is handling this.

Comment: Drat, I'm not sure where that other interference is coming from because it's still defaulting to sorting by date of entry. `nasc_population_code` should be a custom field. We enter data into it with each post and it shows up in the post summary screen (under the heading "pop'n code"): [image](http://www.nasarracenia.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Grow-report-guide-9.png) - I'll have more time this weekend to track down the interference more.

Comment: Hope we don't get flagged for 'extended commenting'! :) I'm confused as to why this isn't working for you when I used it on some sample portfolio posts that I had locally (especially so because I was so proud of solving this complex query business).  Be sure to disable all your plugins... and empty all caches.  Maybe remove the rest of the code in your functions.php.  Good luck!